# How to improve one-time pad cryptosystem?

Tags: cryptography

In the one-time pad cryptosystem, the key generation algorithm might output the all-zeros string, and in such a case the encryption of any message is simply the message itself. Thus, to increase security she suggests modifying the cryptosystem so that it re-samples the key until this is not the case.

I wonder whether this algorithm increase the security.

Algorithm K:

```
   Do K ←$ {0, 1}^k  until k doesnt equal to 0^k
   Return K
```

Thank you so much.

Comment: This would certainly get better answers at http://crypto.stackexchange.com. In fact, it already has! See [One-time pad and zero key](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/3992/one-time-pad-and-zero-key) on Crypto.SE.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a theoretical cryptographic concern, not about a programming problem.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realize there's a crypto stack.

Comment: I'm inclined to say that it would decrease security, but it's most likely negligible depending on the pad length

Answer (score -1):

No, it will not. This just eliminates one case an attacker has to deal with and now an attacker starts out with extra information they wouldn't otherwise have -- the input cannot possibly be identical to the output.

You can make this same argument for *any* pad, not just all zeroes. Imagine I generate some random pad. I can say "hey, we shouldn't allow this pad, because an attacker might check for this pad first and if we happened to use it, they'd have it on their first try."

It wouldn't benefit an attacker to check for an all-zeroes pad before others any more than it would benefit the attacker to check for any other pad first. The probability of any particular pad being correct is equal for all possible pads.